# App crash when installed on a physical device Error: DISPLAY_NAME column is null

Tags: android

I created an app and tried to install it on a physical device. The device immediately crash when I tried to run it. The app works fine in the emulator. My phone is Samsung Galaxy A30 (Android 11). The app's `minSdkVersion` is  23 and `targetSdkVersion` is 31. My app lets user to create list of their subjects, grades and create alarm for their class.

Full error I got from my phone:

```
com.aefyr.sai.model.filedescriptor.ContentUriFileDescriptor$BadContentProviderException: DISPLAY_NAME column is null
    at com.aefyr.sai.model.filedescriptor.ContentUriFileDescriptor.name(ContentUriFileDescriptor.java:30)
    at com.aefyr.sai.model.apksource.DefaultApkSource.getApkLocalPath(DefaultApkSource.java:47)
    at com.aefyr.sai.model.apksource.FilterApkSource.getApkLocalPath(FilterApkSource.java:60)
    at com.aefyr.sai.model.apksource.FilterApkSource.nextApk(FilterApkSource.java:28)
    at com.aefyr.sai.installer2.impl.rootless.RootlessSaiPackageInstaller.install(RootlessSaiPackageInstaller.java:93)
    at com.aefyr.sai.installer2.impl.rootless.RootlessSaiPackageInstaller.lambda$enqueueSession$0$RootlessSaiPackageInstaller(RootlessSaiPackageInstaller.java:70)
    at com.aefyr.sai.installer2.impl.rootless.-$$Lambda$RootlessSaiPackageInstaller$ivyAcunEgIkYlu_dB2vN6MOWZPU.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Comment: seems like someone else had a similar problem https://app.bountysource.com/issues/99611830-error-when-opening-file-from-download-manager-notification, seems to be specific your device perhaps

Comment: huh that person also uses a Samsung phone. Is that a possible reason?

Comment: apparently, although i've got no idea. try loading it onto your phone another way

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is in Provider.
You cannot use some paths to files normally in Android 11 anymore.
Create a file provider.xml with something like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Add necessary paths (Read about Content provider).
After this use Uri like:

```
 Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                requireContext(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                file);
```

Add to Manifest:

```
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider" />
        </provider>
```

May you provide the code where this error appears?

Comment: Those errors I got from my phone and not from the logcat in android studio. My phone just shows the error in a dialog. None of the .java file that is mention on the error I recognize. 


Where should I put the Uri that you showed?

Comment: @Nomel interesting. okay, that was just an idea